# Inherited page in a child publication doesn't seem to be stored correctly in the database

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-1.7

So I hit the following problem:

In a page we have a component that contain some metadata. The page work absolutely fine, when I publish it on the parent publication. When I try to publish the same page (inherited) in a child publication, the metadata of that component is missing. The entity for the component in the DXA doesn't contain the metadata.

There are 2 possible causes for that. The first one is the automatic model binding is not working properly or the data isn't being stored properly in the database. Since the same schema/model is being used by both the parent and child publication, I am leaning toward the latter.

Have any of you have such issues before? Do you have any idea what may cause this bug and how I can investigate further?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you verified what data is stored in the database?
is it also possible that the page is inherited from the parent, but that the component on that page is localized, and doesn't have the expected metadata values?

Comment: I would be _extremely_ surprised if it was a database issue, this is not something I have seen in 15+ years of Tridion experience.

Comment: Are you using same codebase for both of the publications?

Comment: The component is not localized in the child publication and I am using the same codebase for both of the publications. So I just checked the database. The metadata in the component is stored in the database correctly.

Comment: Is the templating the same in both publications that you're publishing from? For example, has a Component Template or Page Template been localised, and are you perhaps using different/extra TBBs? If not, then you may have hit upon a bug in DXA and might want to contact SDL Support.

Answer (score 4):

We managed to fix this issue and I would like to share the solution.

In the binary data, the mapping wasn't up to date in the child publication (didn't contain the metadata fields). I tried several times to publish Publish Settings and admin/refresh, but it didn't fix the file.

What we did at the end was to unpublish the Publish Settings in the parent and childs publications and then publish the Publish Settings again. It does fix the mapping file, thus fixing the issues

Cheers